# Does Strapi run in Free Tier AWS t3.micro?

Tags: strapi

> t2.small is the smallest instance type in which Strapi runs. t2.nano
>   and t2.micro DO NOT work. At the moment, deploying the Strapi Admin
>   interface requires more than 1g of RAM. Therefore, t2.small or larger
>   instance is needed.

[image: heroku prices]

But Heroku's hobby has only 512Mb of Ram.

If 2Gb ram is necessary then, how come deployment to **Heroku Hobby** is possible?

#### Did anyone really try AWS t3.micro?

[image: aws micro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is possible to deploy a Strapi application using Free plan of Heroku.

I did a short video to show you how to do - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qd-xpaT0c48&list=PL7Q0DQYATmvhlHxHqfKHsr-zFls2mIVTi&index=2&t=0s

After that, you can also deploy your Strapia app on AWS using a t3.micro.

Comment: What do you mean by *after that*? Do I have to deploy to heroku first?

Comment: I have created my project locally, now I want to use the free plan of AWS. Is it possible?

Comment: Ho no, I'm mean you can deploy Strapi on Heroku and AWS - depending on the platform you want.
Yes you can deploy Strapi on the free plan of AWS.

Comment: @JimLAURIE Could you give some information how to deploy to AWS free plan? I’m sorry, but I just don’t understand how the process will go.